# Jquery проверка multiselect на :selected options

Tags: html, jquery

Собственно, как сделать проверку на выделенные элементы мультиселекта или их отсутствие при смене количества оных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посчитать выделенные элементы в мультиселекте, а дальше уже производить необходимые манипуляции с переменной `selected` в зависимости от логики. Например, вывести количество выделенных пунктов в `html`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').change(function() {
        var selected = 0;
        $('#list option:selected').each(function(){
            selected++;
        });
        $('#result').text(selected);
    });
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
    <option value="5">Opt 5</option>
    <option value="6">Opt 6</option>
</select>
<hr />
Выбрано элементов: <span id="result">0</span>
```

Comment: <code>$('#list').change(function() {
        var selected = 0;
        $("#list option:selected").each(function(){
            selected++;
        });
        $('#result').text(selected);
    });</code> eto mojno izmenit s <code>$('#list').change(function() {
        var selected = $("#list option:selected").length;
        $('#result').text(selected);
    });</code>

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет, но задача оказалась более тривиальной, мне нужно просто знать, есть ли выделенные элементы или нет, решение:
`$('#socialPostModalDialog #groups').change(function(){
   if ($(this).has('option:checked')) {
    $(this).closest('.controls-row').children('select#message_type_groups').show();
   }
   else {
    $(this).closest('.controls-row').children('select#message_type_groups').hide();
   }
  });`